# IndexedDB MANIFEST grows to 15GB crashing the browser

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, leveldb, dexie

I think I am running into this issue https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/299

I use Dexie and my app run for many days. The data stored are not so large, and the number of entries are fixed, but an array field in each entry get appended every now and then. The MANIFEST file has grown to 15GB and I can no longer access my web site since it freezes and crashes the browser whenever it access IndexedDB.

How do I solve/workaround this issue?